# Does Candace play musical instruments on days other than mom's birthday?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

In the *Phineas and Ferb* season 1 episode “Mom's birthday”, we find that Candace plays several musical instruments: bongos, bugle, bassoon, bagpipe, bass, banjo, balalaika.  (She also considered taking blender lessons in “Flop starz”.)

[image: (instruments)]

But I don't recall Candace playing any musical instrument in later episodes.  She has lots of opportunities, because the show is full of music, and the other main characters do play instruments.  Despite that, it seems like Candace always just sings.  Am I missing something? Is there any other episode where Candace plays a musical instrument?  Or did she give that up completely when her instruments disappeared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Unfair Science Fair Redux (Another Story)

Candace uses an alien's head to play some notes.

[image: Candace wearing a crown, holding the antenna of a green alien with three eyes and twanging it]

She later remarks that "every part of their body is a musical instrument," so I say it counts.

#### Cheers For Fears

We see a scrapbook recreation of her playing an instrument, though the lyrics suggest she isn't actually very good at it.

[image: Candice holding a blue electric guitar outdoors]

#### It's No Picnic

For about two seconds before it cuts to her with a microphone.

[image: Candice onstage holding a pink electric guitar, alongside another muscian]

#### Last Day of Summer

[image: Candice on a large outdoor stage, holding a red and white electric guitar with her brother Ferb]

Comment: So is she ambidextrous?

Answer (score 3):

Although Candace doesn't play them, the instruments are mentioned again in season 4, in the episode “Great Balls of Water”.

> Cadence: Predictable? Ordinary? I mean, come on! I play 20 instruments! Yeah, that all start with the letter "B", as in boring.